# Check if each div is empty and then remove it

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup:

```
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext">Product1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext">Product4</div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to select with jQuery the `.producttext` divs that are empty and then remove them.

I'm trying with this code but it's not working:

```
    $('.producttext').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':empty')){
          $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

Any idea what's the problem with my code?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you mean by "*it's not working.*" What doesn't it do? What does it do instead?

Comment: When you have a `$().each()` call with just jQuery calls inside it, there's often a good chance you can do it without needing the `each()`.

Comment: I have see now that my `producttext` are not empty at all, it has some spaces on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code it remove only the `.producttext` div which is empty, the parent div `.product` will be there.

I think you want to remove the `.product` div then you can use **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** selector

```js
$('.product:has(.producttext:empty)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext">Product1</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext">Product4</div>
</div>
```

Or you just want to remove `.producttext` then use

```js
$('.product .producttext:empty').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext">Product1</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext">Product4</div>
</div>
```

**Update :**

> **[:empty](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)** - Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).
>   Taken from https://api.jquery.com/filter/

So whitespace in your code will treat as textNode so you need to use the below method using **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** and **[`$.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)**(or **[`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)**)

```js
$('.product').filter(function() {
  //return $(this).text().trim() == '';
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == '';
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext">Product1</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext"></div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="producttext">Product4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this still doesn't explain why his solution isn't working

Comment: If the `div` has spaces inside it still work with `:empty`? I think that's my problem

Comment: which will only remove empty `.producttext` div not it's parent

Comment: from the api [:empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)  `Description: Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).`

Comment: thanks, the one with trim worked. I think it had to do with the spaces inside the divs

Comment: as a warning `trim()` isn't supported in older browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Browser_compatibility - though it probably isn't as much of an issue now.  But using jquery's trim method is preferred for compatibility reasons unless you want to shim it.  `$.trim($(this).text())`

Answer (score 1):

If there is whitespace or textnodes, you should probably trim it

```js
$('.producttext')
  .filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length === 0;
  }).remove();  //or .closest(".product").remove();
```

```css
.producttext {
  min-height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
        <div class="producttext">Product1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext">          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext">   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="producttext">Product4</div>
    </div>
```